# Chef and Three dog solution

Tags: c, algorithm

Recently I came across a question on Codechef known as [Chef and Three dogs](https://www.codechef.com/OCT16/problems/CHDOGS/). The question look pretty easy but I'm not getting the logic. Question is as follow:

Chef has three dogs sitting at the vertices of an equilateral triangle. The length of each side of the triangle equals to s meters. Chef gives the command "Start!" and each dog starts to run with constant speed v meters per second. At each moment, each dog is running towards the dog just right to him (in counter-clockwise direction). Therefore, their trajectories are forming some spirals that converging to one point as illustrated below.
[image: sample example image as given is here:]

I have gone through some correct submission but i was unable to figure out why the answer is (2/3)*(s/v)?

here is the sample accepted code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int T,s,v;
    double t;
    scanf("%d\n",&T);
    while(T--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&s,&v);
        t = (2.0*s)/(3.0*v);
        printf("%f\n",t);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be a better question for this site if you posted the code used.

Comment: @chux Most submissions (e.g. mine) literally read pairs of s and v and print 2/3 times s/v. I got to 2/3 through simulation.

Comment: To best explain the results of your simulation, post the code used.

Comment: I have successfully posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be easily visualized by noticing the symmetry defined in the question.

The first step is to understand that because of the inherent symmetry in the positions and motions of the three dogs, their positions at any given time will always form equilateral triangle as shown in the figure.

[image]

Now assume that you are sitting on one of the dogs(It's strange, but assume it nevertheless. :P). For you, the equilateral triangle will keep on decresing in size till it finally collapses, the point where the dogs meet. So, this will be your view at any point of time.

[image]

To an observer sitting on one of the dogs, the components of velocities of its adjacent dog at any given point of time are
depicted in the third figure.

[image]

Thus, any given dog feel that
while it is moving towards its adjacent dog at a speed v, the adjacent dog is moving towards it at a speed v/2. Thus the dogs seem to approach each other at a constant rate of `v + v/2 = 3v/2`. Since the initial distance was `s`, the time takes to meet is given by, `s/(3v/2)` = `2s/3v`.

Comment: Thank you very much for solution but I have trouble in understanding last part that is calculation part.

Comment: When two trains travel towards each other with speed `v` and the starting distance between them is `s`, the time taken for them to pass each other = `s/2v`. `2v` because of their relative speed[Remember class 8th standard math problem]. Similarly here, the relative speed is `v+vcos60` = `v+v/2` = `3v/2`. So time = `s/(3v/2)` = `2s/3v`.

Comment: I get it. Very good explanation.